# Difference between @FeignClient and @EurekaClient

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

What is the key difference between these two annotations?
What is the use of EurekaClient and FeignClient?

Can we expose our endpoints using EurekaClient?

Answer (score 0):

@Feignclient annotation is used for load balancing & @EurekaClient is to get the registered applications from Eureka server.

Comment: Thanks for the response Thirumal, but it would be better if you share more details.

Comment: For eureka server/client refer https://github.com/M-Thirumal/eureka-server & https://github.com/M-Thirumal/eureka-client-1

Comment: Refer the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901054/spring-cloud-how-to-get-benefits-of-retry-load-balancing-and-circuit-breaker-f/32464499#32464499