# Ribbon Retry properties not respected

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-retry, netflix-ribbon

I have a zuul gateway application, that receives requests from a client app and forwards the requests using load balanced rest template to a micro service with 2 endpoints, say endpoint1 and endpoint2 (load balancing between the two end points in round robbin which is okay for now, although I want it to be availability based).

Here are the issues I am facing -

- I brought down one of the end points, say endpoint2 and tried calling the zuul route and I see that when the request is going to the endpoint2 - zuul takes 2 mins or so before failing with HTTP 503 and does not retry on the next request. the error is just cascaded back to the caller.
- Also, even after setting the read time out and connect timeout configurations, I don't see ribbon respecting the configuration and still takes 2 mins to throw the error from the server.
- I tried enabling logs at the netflix package level, but I am unable to see logs unless I pass a custom http client to rest template.

I am new to netflix stack of components...  please advise if I am missing something obvious. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>zuul-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>zuul-gateway</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Zuul</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.242</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.netflix-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>netflix-commons-util</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and my application.yml looks like below -

```
eureka:
client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    lease:
      duration: 5
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

ingestWithOutEureka:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
    listOfServers: http://demo-nlb-6a67d59c901ecd128.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com,http://demo-nlb-124321w2a123ecd128.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    okToRetryOnAllOperations: true
    ConnectTimeout: 500
    ReadTimeout: 1000
    MaxAutoRetries: 5
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 5
    MaxTotalHttpConnections: 500
    MaxConnectionsPerHost: 100
    retryableStatusCodes: 404,503
    okhttp:
      enabled: true

zuul:
  debug:
    request: true
    parameter: true
  ignored-services: '*'
  routes:
    ingestServiceELB:
      path: /ingestWithoutEureka/ingest/**
      retryable: true
      url: http://dummyURL

management.security.enabled : false

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-gateway
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      retry:
        enabled: true

logging:
  level:
    org:
      apache:
        http: DEBUG
    com:
      netflix: DEBUG

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

and my application class looks like below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ZuulGatewayApplication {

    @Bean
    public InterceptionFilter addInterceptionFilter() {
        return new InterceptionFilter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and lastly my zuul filter looks like below - 
    package com.zuulgateway.filter;

```
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class InterceptionFilter extends ZuulFilter{
    private static final String REQUEST_PATH = "/ingestWithoutEureka";

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate loadBalanced() {
        //RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    @LoadBalanced
    private RestTemplate loadBalancedRestTemplate;

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "route";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
        String method = request.getMethod();
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        return requestURI.startsWith(REQUEST_PATH);
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        try {
            String requestPayload = ctx.getRequest().getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

            String response = loadBalancedRestTemplate.postForObject("http://ingestWithOutEureka/ingest", requestPayload, String.class);

            ctx.setResponseStatusCode(200);
            ctx.setResponseBody(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ctx.setResponseStatusCode(500);
            ctx.setResponseBody("{ \"error\" : " + e.getMessage() + " }");
            System.out.println("Exception during feign call - " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
            ctx.getResponse().setContentType("application/json");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here are the solutions that worked for me -

**Issue 1** - Retry was not working in spite of configuring `ribbon.<client>.OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true`. Ribbon was clearly ignoring my configuration.

**Solution:** - It's strange, but after some debugging I had noticed that Ribbon was picking up client level configuration only if a global configuration was present in the first place.

Once I set the global "OkToRetryOnAllOperations" as either "true" or "false" as shown below, ribbon started picking up the `ribbon.<client>.OkToRetryOnAllOperations` as expected and I could see the retries happening.

```
ribbon:
  OkToRetryOnAllOperations: false
```

**Issue 2** - *Also, even after setting the read time out and connect timeout configurations, I don't see ribbon respecting the configuration and still takes 2 mins to throw the error from the server*

**Solution 2** - Though ribbon started retrying requests after the changes suggested in solution 1 above, I did not see ribbon honoring `<client>.ribbon.ReadTimeout` and `<client>.ribbon.ConnectTimeout`.

After spending some time, I figure that this is because of using `RestTemplate`.

While spring documentation mentions that you could use `load balanced RestTemplate` [for achieving retries](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#retrying-failed-requests), it does not mention that the timeouts wont work with it. Based on this [SO answer from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285711/829542), it looks like while [ribbon has been added as a interceptor](http://ryanjbaxter.com/cloud/spring%20cloud/spring/2017/03/15/retrying-http-requests-in-spring-cloud-netflix.html) when using `load balanced RestTemplate` to achieve serviceId to URI resolution, ribbon does not use the underlying HTTP client and uses the http client provided by the `RestTemplate`. Thus, the ribbon specific `<client>.ribbon.ReadTimeout` and `<client>.ribbon.ConnectTimeout` are NOT honored. After I added timeouts to `RestTemplate`, requests have started timing out at expected intervals.

Lastly, 
**Issue 3** - I enabled logs by passing a custom http client to rest template.

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
RestTemplate loadBalanced() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    System.out.println("returning load balanced rest client");
    ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(1000*30);
    ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(1000*3);
    ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000*3);
    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
LoadBalancedBackOffPolicyFactory backOffPolicyFactory() {
    return new LoadBalancedBackOffPolicyFactory() {
        @Override
        public BackOffPolicy createBackOffPolicy(String service) {
            return new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        }
    };
}
```

With all the changes I see that the request retries are happening and with the timeouts and with exponential backoff and with request / responses logs visible as expected. Good luck!